# Date Time Display Issue

Tags: xcode, cocoa-bindings

I have the following code:

```
NSString *dateString = @"01-02-2010 12:00:00 AM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy h:m:s a"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter release];
```

When I set the above date in a DateTimePopup it shows "02/01/2010".

But when I use the same to add data to a GridView it shows
Full Date with Time and Zone.

I need to display only Date ie "02/01/2010"

kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the date format for display:

```
NSString *dateString = @"01-02-2010 12:00:00 AM";  
NSDateFormatter *inputDateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[inputDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy h:m:s a"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [inputDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSDateFormatter *displayDateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[displayDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSString *displayDateString = [displayDateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
NSLog(@"displayDateString: %@", displayDateString);
```

NSLog output
displayDateString: 02/01/2010

Note: In the OP code the line
`NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];`
is unnecessary, on the very next line `dateFromString` is over written.